# When should 'es' be used and when not?

Tags: sentence-structure

I've come across the following passage:

> Ziel ist ***es*** jedoch nicht, die einzelnen Nationalsprachen zu
>   verdrängen.

This is something I'm often confused by. Would it be wrong to omit 'es', as in:

> Ziel ist jedoch nicht, die einzelnen Nationalsprachen zu
>   verdrängen.

?

and is there a general rule on when and when not to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can omit *es* here, but it makes it easier the sentence easier to understand, especially if the standard sequence is used, as in

> Es ist jedoch nicht das Ziel, ...

because *Ziel* is not the subject of the sentence. It finally becomes clear in all of the variants, but you save the reader some effort to decode the sentence possibly requiring reconsideration, when the end of the sentence is reached.

To give a counter-example with the (in my opinion: more likely) construction:

> Politik ist nicht, was x und y auf Twitter veranstalten.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt im Deutschen einfach diese Form von Sätzen ohne konkretes Subjekt. Es ist eine gute Idee, solche Ausdrücke zu kennen (unten sind einige aufgeführt), damit man sie im Alltag benützen kann. Es bringt aber, glaube ich, nicht viel, hier eine allgemeine Theorie zu suchen. Es ist praktischer, diese Form einfach zu verwenden.

> Es wäre schön, du würdest mal dein Zimmer aufräumen.
>
> Es regnet.
>
> Es gehört sich nicht, in der Nase zu bohren.
>
> Es muss nicht immer Kaviar sein.
>
> Es täte dir gut, mal in den Wald zu gehen.
>
> Es tut mir leid, dass ich so vergesslich bin.
>
> Es hätte schlimmer kommen können.
>
> Es hat wenig Sinn, sich über eine Theorie des "es" den Kopf zu zerbrechen.

Comment: Thank you, but I meant when we have two clauses, with one explaining the other.

Comment: And could you please say whether the second sentence (the one without 'es') is correct?

Comment: The second sentence (without 'es') is technically correct, but you would find such a sentence rather in a bureaucratic or academic piece of writing, not in everyday language. The more 'natural' way for the German mind is using the *es* here.

Comment: PS. I do not quite understand what you mean by "one clause explaining the other". Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I mean in English you say: "The goal is not to replace the national languages."
These sentences are often structured in German by using two clauses separated by a comma, like: "Ziel ist nicht es, die Nationalsprachen zu verdrängen."
But sometimes they are written in one clause: "Das Ziel ist nicht die Nationalsprachen zu verdrängen."
So I wanted to know when to use 'es' and when not in this particular context.

Comment: Correctly written also your "Ziel ist nicht, die Nationalsprachen zu verdrängen" has a comma (quite like "Ziel ist es nicht, die Nationalsprachen zu verdrängen"). Does this then constitute two clauses for you? - The rule is that "zu + Infinitiv" clauses have to be separated by comma. It has nothing to do with the use of "es".